# Powershell CSV file to Excel into multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a CSV that has 3 pieces of information (Name, Metric, Metric Data) for each server

```
Server1,Disk/,Disk Metrics
Server1,Disk/logs,Disk Logs Metrics
Server1,MEM/,CPU Metrics
Server2,Disk/,Disk Metrics
Server2,Disk/logs,Disk Logs Metrics
Server2,MEM/,CPU Metrics
```

I want to use powershell to take that CSV file and create a an excel spread sheet where each metric, ServerName, Metric, and Metric Data is written to its own worksheet.

I have added `Install-Module -Name ImportExcel`

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) module for this.

Comment: I'd use the ComObject, I like the ComObject. I think it's fun to watch Excel just do stuff on its own. But that aside, what have you done to try and accomplish this task? Do you have code that we can help you with, or were you just hoping that somebody would write it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exporting to multiple WorkSheets using the [ImportExcel Module](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) could be a bit hard to do if it's your first time using it, normally we would ask for, at least, and attempt at solving this problem but since I already have the code at my disposal I will share a minimal example and leave it to you to do further research on this awesome module.

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'path\to\file.csv'
$path = '\path\to\file.xlsx'

$params = @{
    AutoSize   = $true
    TableStyle = 'Medium11'
    PassThru   = $true
    AutoFilter = $true
}

Remove-Variable xlsx -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$csv | Group-Object Name | ForEach-Object {
    $params.WorkSheetName = $_.Name
    $params.TableName = $_.Name
    $params.InputObject = $_.Group
    if(-not $xlsx) {
        $xlsx = Export-Excel @params -Path $path
        $params.ExcelPackage = $xlsx
        return
    }
    $null = Export-Excel @params
}

Close-ExcelPackage $xlsx
```

Now, if we inspect the `Xlsx`:

```
PS /> Get-Item ./file.xlsx | Get-ExcelFileSummary | Format-Table

ExcelFile WorksheetName Rows Columns Address Path
--------- ------------- ---- ------- ------- ----
file.xlsx Server1          4       3 A1:C4   /home/user/Documents/test
file.xlsx Server2          4       3 A1:C4   /home/user/Documents/test

PS /> Import-Excel ./file.xlsx -WorksheetName Server2

Name    Metric    Metric Data
----    ------    -----------
Server2 Disk/     Disk Metrics
Server2 Disk/logs Disk Logs Metrics
Server2 MEM/      CPU Metrics
```